# Flyway with 2 Database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I use *Spring Boot* with *Flyway* and now I need to use it with 2 databases, today this is my properties file:

```
flyway.validateOnMigrate=false
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
flyway.check-location=false
flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
flyway.sql-migration-prefix=V
flyway.sql-migration-suffix=.sql
flyway.enabled=true
```

So How can I configure to use another connection (with another dir from my migrations)?

Comment: You may have to manually configure the migration instances if you want multiples.

Comment: @chrylis do you know where I need to does this? need to be. after application start, but before conect to db tks

Comment: I'd read `FlywayAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281229/multiple-datasources-migrations-using-flyway-in-a-spring-boot-application/39409113.